# Reduce slug size for Heroku with Play! 2.0 & Scala

Tags: scala, deployment, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a specific problem but the solutions are hopefully probably generic for similar problems.

I have a [Play! framework 2.0](http://www.playframework.org) project, using Scala.

I am trying to deploy a new version to [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com).

However for this project the deployment fails as the [slug size](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size) is too big (101MB).

Now [this app is very simple](http://github.com/flurdy/shoppinglist), so it is most likely a configuration problem. The current deployed version is/was using Play! 2.0-RC3 and the one I am trying to deploy is using version 2.0. That may be an issue?

I have tried to use a .[slugignore](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#ignoring_files_with_) file, ignoring .ivy2, project/boot etc, but to no avail.

Any other suggestions for how to reduce the slug size? When Using Play 2.x and Scala?

[Here is the git push output](https://gist.github.com/2644086) (excluding the Selenium dependencies is probably a start)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the instructions on the bottom of [this](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/ProductionHeroku) page. You simply fork https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala and change the bin/compile script towards its end as described in the **Finetunig** section.

Comment: this is not necessary anymore, the fixes are already in Heroku's default buildpack (you can clone it and verify)

Comment: I just pushed the shoppinglist and the slug was 77.8MB.  But when I do a `sbt stage` locally my directory is 37.7MB.  So I don't think the buildpack change has gone into effect yet.  For details on how to fix this, check out: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/play-framework/slug$20size/play-framework/R_BbIomWsqI/X9LA8c6y2LcJ

Comment: This is the link to when I originally asked

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/R_BbIomWsqI

Comment: Thanks Drew for fixing my link.  I just tried the new version of the buildpack and it reduced the slug size to 47.5MB.  To use the new buildpack do: `heroku create -s cedar --buildpack http://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala.git` or the following might work on an existing app: `heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=http://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala.git`

Comment: The heroku config:add command solved the problem. Slug size is now 47.5Mb.Thanks :)

Comment: @JamesWard I checked yesterday downloading Heroku's slug and it seemed the code was in, although I may have checked the wrong repo!

Comment: @PereVillega The code is in the repo but it's not in production on Heroku yet.

Comment: @JamesWard ah, that's why I got confused then! Any estimate?

Comment: @PereVillega  Not sure.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** as of the time of this post the code was in the buildpack repository but not yet live, as per @JamesWard comments. I assume it will be released soon :)

I see that your application was started a few months ago. Try to remove the Heroku application and create it again from scratch.

Heroku's buildpack already contains the changes listed by Fynn to reduce slug size (tested yesterday), but if your aplication is old it may be that the changes were not added. Of course, you could modify your buildpack, but it may be simpler to just recreate the app.

Comment: Would probably have solved the problem. But I didn't want to migrate the data etc, and in the end using James' heroku buildpack command worked on the existing instance.